# Firebase dynamic link: can`t create short link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

So, I've implemented `FirebaseDynamicLinks` like this:

```
val link = "https://test/?promo=$uId"
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("test.page.link")
            .setAndroidParameters(
                    DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("test")
                            .setMinimumVersion(1)
                            .build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnSuccessListener { shortDynamicLink ->
                val mInvitationUrl = shortDynamicLink.shortLink.toString()
                log("test1 success $mInvitationUrl")
                //shareIntent(mInvitationUrl)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                log("test1 fail")
                it.printStackTrace()
            }
```

but calling `.buildShortDynamicLink()` throws me an exception:

`W: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400: Long link is not parsable: test.page.link/generatedLongLink [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]`

and what's interesting: inserting `test.page.link/generatedLongLink` in browser works as intended - on android it directs me on google play page and on pc it directs me on web site that I specified in firebase consile when I was creating dynamic link

so what's the problem with calling  `.buildShortDynamicLink()` and how can I fix it?

Comment: As I alway suggest use `"Divide et Impera"` approach and try with less code and only later add more. So try only the basic parameters in order to create a shortlink like `link`, `domainUriPrefix` (with **https://**) and nothing more. And then add `Android Parameters`, `iOS parameters` and only at the very end add `listeners`. Moreover the error tells you that ***Long Link is not parsable***... so try with a simple `https://test` and then add query string params

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried this code for you

```
    val uId = 1234241

    val link = "https://www.test.com/$uId"
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
        .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
        .setDomainUriPrefix("https://example.page.link")
        .setAndroidParameters(
            DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("test")
                .setMinimumVersion(1)
                .build())
        .buildShortDynamicLink()
        .addOnSuccessListener { shortDynamicLink ->
            val mInvitationUrl = shortDynamicLink.shortLink.toString()
            Log.d("AAA","test1 success $mInvitationUrl")
            //shareIntent(mInvitationUrl)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("AAA", "test1 fail")
            it.printStackTrace()
        }
```

and ***it works fine***.

If instead I didn't put **"https://"** on my dynamic link, I get your error.

[image]

So change

```
.setDomainUriPrefix("test.page.link")
```

with

```
.setDomainUriPrefix("https://test.page.link")
```

And all should work fine:

[image]